# Equation to select desired curve

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, statistics, discrete-mathematics, mathematical-physics

I have three plots from three different algorithms developed, plot #1 (proposal-2) is what i want to get from equation to be developed since it has less number of accidents (y axis values on average from 40 to 80 nodes) against x-axis (traffic nodes), when compared with Standard-Algo, the plot is shown below
[image]

The type of values that could be in a plot to be compared against desired plot are shown in two more plots. For example in the plot shown below the accidents are quite less (91% decrease than standard algo) with 40 nodes but later on from 50 to 80 nodes the accidents are quite high, although overall sum of %decrease shown in red is high that makes overall accidents sum smaller than proposal-2 but still proposal 1 is desirable due low accidents (high % decrease on average) in operating range from 40 to 80 nodes.
[image]

Similarly with this graph (proposal-1) below there is (negative %Decrease) more number of collisions at 80 nodes, so this plot is also not desirable

[image]

Now how can i develop an equation that gives me proposal-2 curve be selected given values of accidents at each point. I can easily do last case that has negative %Decrease but how can i get proposal-2 instead of proposal-3

Comment: You'll probably get a better answer over at [Cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I think you are asking about interpolation. See [*cubic spline interpolation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) which gives you different curves between each pair of data points, but the curves match up smoothly. If you do not need accuracy you could use simple linear interpolation between data points (ie using the blue lines). If you want to draw a straight line or smooth curve which does not pass through the points you could investigate linear or non-linear regression.

Comment: I solved it by considering collisions of referenced and proposed algorithms.